# how to visualize all data having different range

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I have a dataset following below:
data = {{0.1,3}, {0.3, 0.03}, {0.5, 0.04}, {0.1, 0.02}, {0.2,
0.08}, {0.45, 0.09}};
I want to break the y axis thats why I can show all data in a single plot.
I am using mathematica10.

How to I do this.

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Search this forum for solutions before posting a new question. Here are [the (many) results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Break+axis) of a search on "break axis". One oh those should work for you.

Comment: Have you seen `ListLogPlot`?  With this, you seem not to need to break the axis.